How to use custom message arrays in a service response with Python?
I'm trying to populate a service response array in a Python coded service node and I'm getting an assertion violations from one of the IDL generated files.
The service Service.srv definition is the following:
string req
---
my_interfaces/MyCustomResponse[] resp

Where MyCustomResponse.msg is defined as following:
int64 an_id

The runtime error is something like:
python3: /projects/my_proj/build/my_interfaces/rosidl_generator_py/my_interfaces/msg/_my_custom_response_s.c:53: my_interfaces__msg__my_custon_response__convert_from_py: Assertion `strncmp("my_interfaces.msg._my_custom_response.MyCustomResponse", full_classname_dest, 54) == 0' failed.
If I remove the array to make the response just a simple MyCustomResponse response, everything works fine.
Are there any issues with the arrays of custom messages in Python written services (the C++ counterpart works fine).
Thanks.

Please consider sharing exactly how you're using it in a minimal example to get the best help.

can you update your Python service advertiser (callback) function like this for a test.
def service_callback(self, request, response):
    # Populate the response array
    response.resp = []  # Initialize the array

    for i in range(5):  # Example of adding 5 items to the array
        custom_resp = MyCustomResponse()
        custom_resp.an_id = i
        response.resp.append(custom_resp)  # Add to the response array

    return response

